# Installing Win7 over PXE through Serva fails on Loading Network Resources

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, pxe

I'm trying to install Win7 OS on a Lenovo E335 with no DVD/CD. I'm doing it over PXE/Network using Serva. 
Although I am able to get passed Serva's installation menu, ServaPENet fails at the booting client when "Loading Network Resources" giving:

```
FAILED No NIC/Driver, ABORTING!
```

This is the only log on the Serva Client PC and nothing on the Serva-server side.
I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to get past this error. The network card works fine; it has already loaded the Windows PE installation structure on a X: drive on the new laptop.

Another detail: I am using a normal Ethernet Cable to connect the PCs. Should this be enough, or is a crossover cable mandatory in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you got to see ServaPENet on your screen saying

> FAILED No NIC/Driver, ABORTING!

then your Ethernet cables are OK; at that moment all the TFTP transfers were correctly done.

The error you mention says the The windoesPE (boot.wim) of the OS you are trying to install does not have the correct drivers for your Lenovo.
The official Serva's how-to clearly says how to solve this problem at 
*8.3.2- WDS OS OEM network drivers*

http://www.vercot.com/~serva/howto/WindowsPXE1.html#troubleshooting

also you can see here the same procedure on a Lenovo

https://s205blog.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/windows-7-pxe-network-install-turorial/

Comment: Thx. Actually I realized that there were instructions on how to solve that problem at Serva. 
Still had some problems with the Serva/PXE. Gave up on windows 7 installation over NET since there were problems with the user-access and installed Windows 8 instead via USB (Windows 8 has drivers for USB3 built in).

Comment: you could've installed Win 7 with the Boot.wim from a Windows 8 distro and avoid the driver issue

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and a big booo for the moderator who thinks what is important and what not.

Comment: @Pat, the exact chapter is `8.3.2- WDS OS OEM network drivers`. Isuggest for you to correct it.

Comment: @Pat, I have tested the `boot.wim` file (216MB size vs 146MB for the Win7SP1 version) from a Windows 8.1, and the network driver issue keeps happening. Anyway, I must admit the machine is a modern ASUS X551CA-SX014H portable.

Comment: I've corrected the chapter. About the driver just get it and inject it with Serva. It is a simple procedure well explained at Serva's webpage